# Disable Text Wrapping on a Dynamically Filled DataGrid WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid

As the title mentions I am creating a `DataGrid` as follows:

```cs
dataGrid = new DataGrid();
dataGrid.ItemsSource = dSet.Tables[i].DefaultView;
```

and adding it inside a `WrapPanel`. Everything is working but I need to disable the text wrapping on rows with multiple lines and limit the column width and having them displaying three dots.

I tried styling the `DataGridCell` but nothing is working for me.

Can anyone help with this?

Note: I cannot create predefined columns since this is a dynamic grid that I cannot determine before what columns it will populate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event and use a converter that converts the long `string` to a shorter one:

```
dataGrid = new DataGrid();
dataGrid.ItemsSource = dSet.Tables[i].DefaultView;
LongTextConverter LongTextConverter = new LongTextConverter();
dataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn += (ss, ee) => 
{
    DataGridTextColumn column = ee.Column as DataGridTextColumn;
    column.Binding = new Binding(ee.PropertyName) { Converter = LongTextConverter };
};
```

**LongTextConverter.cs:**

```
public class LongTextConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string s = value as string;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) && s.Length > 10)
            return $"{s.Substring(0, 7)}...";

        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: i replaced return $"{s.Substring(0, 7)}..."; with return s.Trim().Replace("\r","").Replace("\n",""); and got the needed results. is there a way to hide the whole string and make it visible only by expanding the column. thanks again